# ANDROID Preferences List Preference change values dynamically

Tags: android, preferences, listpreference

I am trying to change the entryvalue of a listpreference depending on wether a checkbox is ticked or not...

```
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);{
    if(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("french", false))
    {

        Preference newsPref = (Preference) findPreference("news_feed");
        newsPref.setDefaultValue("@array/newsfeedfr");

    }
    else
    {
        Preference newsPref = (Preference) findPreference("news_feed");
        newsPref.setEntryValues("@array/newsfeed");

    }

    }
```

i get errors on the .setEntryValue with this:

```
The method setEntryValues(String) is undefined for the type Preference
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue that you have is in how you're referencing your array values. `@array/newsfeed` is used in XML files, not Java!

You probably want to use `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.newsfeed)` or similar. [Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

Another issue is that `setEntryValues()` isn't defined for `Preferences`, you need to initialise as a `ListPreference` instead.

Comment: i changed code to this http://pastebin.com/Dy5LSASd and i get nullpointer exception line 24 (on pastebin this is line 10)

Comment: `getDefaultSharedPreferences` is a method of your `Context`, not `Preference`. You've also missed `getResources().getStringArray()`.

Comment: There are probably half a dozen reasons for this crashing. Use proper indentation and check where you're closing your brackets. At the moment most of your code isn't in a function because onCreate() is closing prematurely after you call `addPreferencesFromResource`.